# Class 'Symfony not found in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to grasp the concept of unit testing in laravel. All of a sudden it started showing an error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException

Class 'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Util\SecureRandom' not found
```

i remember adding

```
"require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
    }
```

to composer.json file, as it was mentioned in the tutorial and has also performed a `composer install`(something like this) command.

Now it's showing the class Symphony error. What to do?

Comment: did you do a `composer dump-autoload -o`?

Comment: also, you wouldn't need to add the phpunit package for *normal* testing, as laravel already builds upon `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your `composer.json` file to use PHPUnit `4.0.*` and update your application.